# help please: xjc throws "Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class"

Tags: web-services, jaxb, jax-ws, wsimport, xjc

Take the following over simplified XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="com.acme" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="Widget">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element 
                    minOccurs="0" name="color" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="WidgetColor" type="xs:string" />
</xs:schema>
```

Then, attempt the following:

```
xjc test.xsd
```

You should invariably get the following exception:

```
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
[ERROR] Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.
  line 11 of file:/C:/test.xsd

[ERROR] (Related to above error) This is the other declaration.
  line 7 of file:/C:/test.xsd

Failed to produce code.
```

Notice that There is an element name "**Widget**" which is a complexType and has elements named "**color**". There is also, at the same level as the element "**Widget**", an simple element named "**WidgetColor**".

What is more puzzling is that if you *remove* the attribute minOccurs="0" ***OR*** you *remove* the attribute nillable="true" from the "color" element sequence, xjc compiles the schema successfully.

Has anyone ever seen this problem or can suggest a solution?

Thanks,

Mike.

Answer (score 7):

Well I finally figured out how to fix my problem. It lies in using a custom binding to specify a distinct class name for one of the declarations.

*Content of custom-binding.xjb*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bindings version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <bindings schemaLocation="test.xsd">
        <bindings node="//xs:element[@name='WidgetColor']">
            <class name="BaseWidgetColor" />
        </bindings>
    </bindings>
</bindings>
```

Operation:

```
C:\>xjc -b custom-binding.xjb test.xsd
parsing a schema...
compiling a schema...
acme\com\BaseWidgetColor.java
acme\com\ObjectFactory.java
acme\com\Widget.java
acme\com\package-info.java
```

*Patience et longueur de temps valent mieux que rage et acharnement...!*